# Why is "a:not(b) > c" invalid?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS:

```
div.section:not(div.cover) > div { ... }
```

And the validator says:

```
Parse Error [div.cover) > div]
```

Why doesn't it validate (not working in browsers either)? Is > not allowed after a pseudo-class, or what could be the issue?

Comment: is this tied to HTML? If so care sharing that with us

Comment: Have you tried using a non-compound selector inside `:not`? E.g. `:not(.cover) > div`?

Comment: adding to @DanPrince's comment: `div.section:not(.cover) > div { ... }` instead of what you have up there

Comment: It's okay if I write just `.cover` instead of `div.cover`, so use a simple selector. That was the problem, thank you!

Comment: @tom you don't need to use `div.section` either. I would not recommend it unless you plan to differentiate what a `.section` is between different HTML elements and as your project/solution escalates the usage of `.section` can become confusing. Just use `.section`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot combine a type selector (`div`) and a class selector (`.cover`) in the negation pseudo-class `:not()`, as pointed out by @DanPrince in the comments.

The negation pseudo-class must contain a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn):

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is `(div.cover)`. You need to give a simple selector e.g. `(.cover)`

Comment: Sorry, I could accept both, but Quantastical was 20 seconds faster :)